# Open a file from SD card in android

Tags: android, android-sdcard, ioexception

To open a file from android application asset folder I used below code:

```
InputStream fis = getApplicationContext().getAssets().open(filename);
```

Same thing I want to open a file from SDcard... How to do?

Comment: There is no consistent concept of an SD card in Android, however for External Storage in general see http://developer.android.com/training/basics/data-storage/files.html#WriteExternalStorage

Answer (score 0):

File file = new File(path);

InputStream in = new FileInputStream(file);

This should work as long as the sdcard is mounted with a valid path.